# How can we attract new solutions to old questions that have already been answered?

Tags: discussion, questions

The following question received an answer more than three years ago.  It was a fine answer at the time, but I can't help but wonder if it could be improved on now.  Is there a good way to incentivize new answers?

[How can I customize the list of services that pops up when I choose to "share" something in an app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1156/how-can-i-customize-the-list-of-services-that-pops-up-when-i-choose-to-share-s)

Comment: See below. Or you draw attention by asking on Meta – answer posted ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could [offer a bounty](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). Two of the possible [canned reasons](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) seem applicable, I would think:

> **Current answers are outdated**
>   The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

Or simply:

> **Draw attention**
>   This question has not received enough attention.

Starting a bounty will put the question on the "featured" questions tab for the duration, and the rep bonus tends to be a good incentive as well.

Comment: I only have 116 points here; is there another good way to do this that won't kill off some of my basic privileges? I can offer minimum bounty without losing anything important, so that is an option (do you think 50 points is enough to attract attention here?), but 100 points will take away my ability to, say, leave comments. I don't care about the points themselves, just the privileges, since I'm on the extreme low end.

Comment: The only other decent option would be to perform some kind of edit to update the question with additional detail/clarity. That would bump it back to the top of the active list, at least. Just be sure that any editing provides improvement to the content (i.e. don't add whitespace or something just to bump it).

Comment: I actually did just that, and the post got a great new answer. However [the edit was rejected](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/79767). I understand why a reviewer would reject at a glance, but I disagree with the reject and believe I have solid reasons; also I believe the edit didn't really change the question. Would you be willing to make the edit, if you think it's valid? I was going to post about it on meta but I thought I'd ask you about it here first, since there's some context in these comments.