# Handling possible duplicate of very old questions?

Tags: discussion

Android as an operating system dates back to 2008, and the first viable Android version (arguably), Gingerbread, was out circa 2011, 6 years earlier. Android.SE itself also has a ~7-year history.

During the course, many questions on meaningful topics have been asked, some could even be considered some sort of "FAQ", as the issue persists across many Android versions, and people outside SE are constantly flowing in (via search) looking for a solution. However, as Android version progresses rapidly and brings a lot of changes with each version, the solution proposed back then might not be as elegant or effective by "modern" standards. This part of the dilemma had been discussed [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/how-can-we-attract-new-solutions-to-old-questions-that-have-already-been-answere).

While I was reviewing close votes recently, I start to notice some duplicate votes, referencing such old questions as its duplicate "target", but the way I see it, the answers there are too outdated or general to be of reference value. Occasionally, there are also factors in the dupe "suspect" that's a result of the advancing of Android or the software in question, and not part of the dupe "target". Marking as dupe in this way won't help the author of the dupe "suspect" get much clue, and his question will probably get closed before it attracts careful inspection from knowledgeable people.

I personally feel that, after a certain time threshold, we should either direct our effort to updating such old questions *before* we assign them as dupe "targets", or when we can't, we should not even check the mark in the first place, but instead leave them as a platform for up-to-date answers to grow on.

What's the meta's opinion on this?

Comment: Totally agreed with you.  There are a lot of the "same" questions that will have completely different answers for Android 2.2 vs 7.0 and shouldn't even be considered duplicates one way or the other.

Comment: Make that 3 of us. We need to get a list from data SE for the older questions, and see what could be filled up to work with today's android as well as older versions.

Comment: My opinion. Whether a new question is a duplicate depends on the applicability of the solution mentioned in the old post. If an old solution still works, then I'd mark new posts as dups, and vice versa. BTW we can edit old posts and add a line in the very beginning saying "This method applies to Android m.n to x.y".